# Randomizing key-value pairs from a hash

Tags: ruby, hash, hashmap, each, key-value

I'm building a simple vocabulary quiz that provides the user with a value from a predetermined hash, and takes his or her response as input. If the user's input matches the value's corresponding key, the program moves on to the next value, and repeats this process until all key-value pairs in the hash have been accounted for.

In its current state, the quiz prompts the user with values from the hash one-by-one, in order, from first to last.

However, to make the quiz more difficult, I would like the quiz to provide RANDOM values from the hash, in no particular order.

Plain English...how do I get the vocab quiz to spit out random definitions from its library, instead of printing the same definitions in the same order every time?

My code is below. Greatly appreciate everyone's help!

```
vocab_words = {
  "class" => "Tell Ruby to make a new type of thing",
  "object" => "Two meanings: The most basic type of thing, and any instance of some thing",
  "instance" => "What you get when you tell Ruby to create a class",
  "def" => "How you define a function inside a class"
}

vocab_words.each do |word, definition|
  print vocab_words[word] + ": "
  answer = gets.to_s.chomp.downcase

    while answer != "%s" %word
      if answer == "help"
        print "The answer is \"%s.\" Type it here: " %word
        answer = gets.to_s.chomp.downcase
      else
        print "Nope. Try again: "
        answer = gets.to_s.chomp.downcase
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: `random_keys = vocab_words.keys.shuffle` like so:

```
vocab_words = {
  "class" => "Tell Ruby to make a new type of thing",
  "object" => "Two meanings: The most basic type of thing, and any instance of some thing",
  "instance" => "What you get when you tell Ruby to create a class",
  "def" => "How you define a function inside a class"
}

random_keys = vocab_words.keys.shuffle
random_keys.each do |word|
  print vocab_words[word] + ": "
  answer = gets.to_s.chomp.downcase

  if answer == "help"
    print "The answer is \"%s.\" Type it here: " %word
    answer = gets.to_s.chomp.downcase
  else
    while answer != "%s" %word
      print "Nope. Try again: "
      answer = gets.to_s.chomp.downcase
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks so much! Used your suggestion and it worked perfectly. Appreciate the help.